# XSLT related tags by attribute in the same output line

Tags: xslt

Trying to make this transformation but couldn't find the answer in the web nor in documentation (newbe here).

Just trying to make something like this:

```
<Info>
        <Type p="1">MyType1</Type>
        <Type p="2">MyType2</Type>
        <Type p="3">MyType3</Type>
        <Values>
            <r p="1">MyValue1</r>
            <r p="2">MyValue2</r>
            <r p="3">MyValue3</r>
        </Values>
</Info>
```

Appear as a plain text transformation like this:

```
MyType1;MyValue1
MyType2;MyValue3
MyType3;MyValue3
```

Being the two field of the output joined by the "p" attribute ¿Is it possible?

Comment: It is a grouping problem, please state whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or whether you need an XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: @Esecede - I presume that the output above has a typo in line 2 - it should read MyType2;MyValue2 not MyType2;MyValue3

Comment: @JohnRC, indeed, there is a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, it's 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple approach

```
<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="newline">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="/Info/Type" >
    <xsl:variable name="p" select="@p" />
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select=" /Info/Values/r[@p=$p] " />
    <xsl:if test=" position() != last() ">
      <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will select only the first matching Values/r node for each of the Type nodes. So the assumption is that any further Values/r nodes with the same @p should be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

XSLT has [a built-in mechanism for handling cross-references](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key); it would be best to use it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="value" match="r" use="@p" />

<xsl:template match="/Info">
    <xsl:for-each select="Type">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('value', @p)">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!= last()">
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>     
        <xsl:if test="position()!= last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is assumed that:

1. Each `Type` entry is unique;
2. There could be more than one value with the same type; for example, the following input:

   ```
   <Info>
   <Type p="1">MyType1</Type>
   <Type p="2">MyType2</Type>
   <Type p="3">MyType3</Type>
   <Values>
       <r p="1">MyValue1</r>
       <r p="2">MyValue2a</r>
       <r p="2">MyValue2b</r>
       <r p="3">MyValue3</r>
   </Values>
   ```

   would return:

   ```
   MyType1;MyValue1
   MyType2;MyValue2a;MyValue2b
   MyType3;MyValue3
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a template matching `Type` printing the value of `Type` followed by the value of the according `r` element and an empty template matching `Values` to avoid printing the `Values` twice like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="Type">
 <xsl:variable name="current" select="@p"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(';',//Values/r[@p=$current])"/>
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
     <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Values"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Applied to your input the following output is produced:

```
MyType1;MyValue1
MyType2;MyValue2
MyType3;MyValue3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this simple and short XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kRByP" match="r" use="@p"/>

 <xsl:template match="Type/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,';',key('kRByP', ../@p), '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<Info>
    <Type p="1">MyType1</Type>
    <Type p="2">MyType2</Type>
    <Type p="3">MyType3</Type>
    <Values>
        <r p="1">MyValue1</r>
        <r p="2">MyValue2</r>
        <r p="3">MyValue3</r>
    </Values>
</Info>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
MyType1;MyValue1
MyType2;MyValue2
MyType3;MyValue3
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using keys, template matching and the way the XSLT processing model works. Only the wanted text-nodes are matched, the rest are ignored ("deleted").
2. Assumptions are that the value of a `p` attribute uniquely identifies the `r` or `Type` element, to which this attribute belongs